# Leveling a concrete Slab

Tags: slab, leveling

If I need to level a slab with a 2' sag in the center, should I pour regular concrete up to 1" before using a leveling compound?

Comment: What are you using it for after leveling? Also you probably mean 2" not 2', unless there is a crater in this slab.

Comment: Did you get foundation piers around the perimeter? How old is this slab?

Comment: What caused it to say? If you pour a top slab, why would you need a leveler?